# Application Submissions to the Azure Gallery vs Web App Gallery

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I know how to submit my application in a web app gallery.

I follow [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureappgallery/archive/2013/03/22/tips-for-a-successful-submission-to-windows-azure-app-gallery.aspx)  to publish my app in the Azure Gallery.

The link redirects me to submit my app from  [this](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/developer.aspx).

I created Manifest and Parameters files but am unable to understand how they distinguish whether it's for the Web App Gallery or the Azure Gallery?

Is there any parameter in Parameters.xml to indicate that it's for Azure Gallery.

Manifest.xml

```
<MSDeploy.iisApp>
  <iisapp path="xxxx" />
  <setAcl path="xxxx" setAclAccess="Modify" />
</MSDeploy.iisApp>
```

And Parameters.xml

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="AppPath" defaultValue="Default Web Site/XXXX" tags="iisapp">
    <parameterEntry type="ProviderPath" scope="iisapp" match="XXXX" />
  </parameter>

  <!-- This is the hidden connection string with the newly created db account that is used in the web.config  -->
  <parameter name="Connection String for Config " description="Connection string to enter into config"
             defaultValue="" tags="SQL,SQLConnectionString,Hidden ">
    <parameterEntry type="XmlFile" scope="\\connectionstring.config" match="//connectionStrings/add[@name='xxxxxxxx']/@connectionString" />
  </parameter>

  <parameter name="SetAclParameter1" defaultValue="{AppPath}" tags="Hidden">
    <parameterEntry type="ProviderPath" scope="setAcl" match="SageFrame" />
  </parameter>

</parameters>
```

Thanks for help.